# @JsonIgnore vs @Transient -difference?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jackson

Which one to use for skipping field for serialization and de-serialization.

**@JsonIgnore** why we should use it if @Transient also skips the field from  serialization and de-serialization process?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The clear difference between the two is that `@Transient` is used as part of JPA to ignore a field from persisting if it is marked as `@Transient`.

Where as `@JsonIgnore` is only used to Ignore a marked field from being serialized, de-serialized to and from JSON.

Which means a field marked as `@JsonIgnore` can still be persisted in a JPA persistence where as a field marked `@Transient` will neither be persisted nor be serialized, de-serialized.

Comment: Why wouldn't `@Transient` fields be de/serialized by Jackson?

Comment: Is there a why to let the serialization but block the persistence ?

Comment: @ErikGillespie my guess is because the annotation is supposed to behave similar to the Java 'transient' keyword. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient#:~:text=transient%20is%20a%20Java%20keyword,object%20state%20to%20serial%20bytes.

Answer (score 4):

We should distinguish between [`javax.persistence.Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) and [`java.beans.Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Transient.html). As mentioned by @shazin and @Abhishek Kumar, the former signals JPA to ignore the property for persistence and does not affect marshalling. Jackson treats the latter the same as [`JsonIgnore`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/2.11/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.java) during marshalling, as can be seen in [`JacksonAnnotationIntrospector#_isIgnorable(Annotated)`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.11/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java):

```
protected boolean _isIgnorable(Annotated a)
{
    JsonIgnore ann = _findAnnotation(a, JsonIgnore.class);
    if (ann != null) {
        return ann.value();
    }
    if (_java7Helper != null) {
        Boolean b = _java7Helper.findTransient(a);
        if (b != null) {
            return b.booleanValue();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

where [`Java7SupportImpl#findTransient(Annotated)`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.11/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/Java7SupportImpl.java) is looking for `java.beans.Transient`.

Comment: Note that Jackson does treat `@javax.persistence.Transient` on fields the same as how it treats `@java.beans.Transient` on methods -- that is, the same as `@JsonIgnore` -- if you have the `Hibernate5Module` registered.  That class is in `jackson-datatype-hibernate5`.  There may be other datatype libraries that also do the same.

Answer (score 3):

`@Transient` is an allegory to `transient` keyword in Java language. When used with a variable, it is never serialized.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    String password;

    public Person(String name, int age, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}

public void serializationTest() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Person aPerson = new Person("Demonte", 37, "bestKeptSecret1995");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(aPerson);

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

By annotating `getPassword()` *(remember getters for serialization)* `@Transient` will produce

```
{"name":"Demonte","age":37}
```

Now if you revisit the `Person` class code and remove `@Transient` and add `transient` to the `password` variable and also add a feature to the Jackson mapper to tell it how to handle fields marked as `transient`

```
transient String password;
```

and

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, true);
```

*(remember Jackson uses getters not members directly for serialization)* then you will get the same output.